Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers

Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.3-6503028-osx Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon.
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

 android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.codeplayon.kids_learning"
        minSdkVersion 19
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 16
        versionName "3.4.6"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[4.0.0, 4.99.99]'
    // Play core library
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0'

}

